# Encryption IV - C and Python equivalent

Tags: python, c, django, encryption, esp32

I have problems regarding initializing equivalent "initialization vectors" for the encryption of my message. 
I have an ESP32 (microcontroller) sending Data via JSON to a Django Server. On the ESP32 I use the Arduino IDE, so the code on the ESP32 is written in C/C++. Django of course is using Python.

My encryption works so far if I intialiaze the IV like this on both sides:

ESP32:

```
unsigned char iv[16] = {'0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0'};
```

Django:

```
iv = b'0000000000000000'
```

The library of the ESP32 has an encryption function which expects an unsigned char array. I have to pay attention that the array is not null-terminated ('\0' at the end) or i get different results.
That are the background informations. you need. Now to my specific problem:

I want to use counter mode in my encryption. I want to copy an integer-counter to the last 4 bytes of the IV on both sides:

On the ESP32 I do:

```
int msg_counter = 15 //15 just as an example
memcpy(iv+12, &msg_counter, sizeof(msg_counter));
```

On Django I do:

```
counter = (int) 15;
iv = counter.to_bytes(16, byteorder = 'big')
```

If I print out the variable "iv" I get this on Django:

```
b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x0f'
```

The decryption fails. I dont get the original message from the ESP32 on the server.

If I dont initialize the IV's like above, I always get different results.

I am using PyCryptoDome for the encryption/decryption on Django.
I am passing the IV to this line of code:
obj = AES.new(enckey, AES.MODE_CFB, iv, segment_size = 128)
The IV must be passed in a format like this b'0000000000000000'. So i dont have any other choices on the server-side.

If I do this on the ESP32:

```
memset(iv,0,16);
```

and

```
b'0000000000000000'
```

on Django I get different results. I dont know what to to.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I kept trying and found it out myself.

On the ESP32 you have to do:

```
int msg_counter = 15;
unsigned char iv[16];
unsigned char bytes[4];
bytes[0] = (msg_counter >> 24) & 0xFF;
bytes[1] = (msg_counter >> 16) & 0xFF;
bytes[2] = (msg_counter >> 8) & 0xFF;
bytes[3] = msg_counter & 0xFF;
memcpy(iv+12, bytes, sizeof(bytes));
```

On Django:

```
counter = 15;
iv = counter.to_bytes(16, byteorder = 'big')
```

Answer (score 0):

According to section 1.3.1 of its [technical manual](https://www.espressif.com/sites/default/files/documentation/esp32_technical_reference_manual_en.pdf), the ESP32 stores data in [little-endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) format. That means that the IV created by:

```
int msg_counter = 15;
memcpy(iv+12, &msg_counter, sizeof(msg_counter));
```

will look like:

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0x0F 0 0 0
```

To achieve the same thing in Python you need to do something like:

```
msg_counter = 15
iv = iv[:12] + msg_counter.to_bytes(4, byteorder="little")
```

Comment: Already tried little Endian but it didnt work. I found the solution myself. Posted a new answer.